# PDFLIB: line breaking is not working, can't find the proper options to set it

Tags: php, line-breaks, pdflib

I am using **pdflib** 9.0.1 on php to generate some text pdfs.

I am stuck on line breaking at the end of the line. I need to place a text on several columns and with `alignment=justify`, so **the word has to be splitted in 2 parts** and the first remains on current line, a dash is set at the end, and the rest goes to the next line. Seems easy, to explain, but I am not getting any result on pdflib.

I've tried creating the textflow with some options like `locale=de_DE`, `advancedlinebreak=true`, `adjustmethod` and also using `script` option, but without success.

The options I found, for controlling the line break algorithm are [here on the PDFlib-9.0.1-API-reference](http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/manuals/PDFlib-9.0.1-API-reference.pdf) on page 92.

If some "*good samaritan*" has some clue, it would be welcome!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the option "avoidbreak=true"